# How to remove Ubuntu but keep GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am in a fix.
1 year ago I dual-booted my system with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10. I was new to ubuntu and didn't want to waste memory so i allocated ubuntu only 15 GB.

Now i love ubuntu so I installed it second time , this time allocating 100 GB (Triple boot).

Now i want to remove the older 15 GB partition but I fear that it will also remove GRUB.

How do I remove the older partition without removing GRUB?

Comment: Your new 'ubuntu' partition should contain the only grub being used.  *note: i'm assuming non-uefi*.    I suspect both your old & new ubuntu partitions will have a grub installed; but only one will have its stage-1 stored on your MBR so it only will be used.  Compare your `grub.cfg` on the two partitions & see which matches what you see on boot; you'll likely find it matches the last install & thus can happily delete the first partition.   (the option will still exist; but it'll disappear when `update-grub` is run by you or an update)

Comment: How will I know which grub is being used by looking at grub.cfg?

Comment: You don't have to know that or be concerned with it (the grub.cfg).  This is automatically handled by the command `sudo update-grub`.  Other details are included in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open gparted (sudo gparted) at terminal, GRUB2 menu is included within a dedicated boot partition, often the first partition labeled as sda1. If you're dual booting with W10 it should be 500MB, and this partition is shared with W10. If you run a UEFI drive you should see its mount point as /boot/efi,and the format as FAT32. With an MBR drive the format is NTFS.

When booting up as long as GRUB2 menu shows your 2 operating systems, and both are accessible from either choice without a problem, you don't have to worry any further about GRUB and you can delete the 15 GB partition. If you intend to keep your 2 OS as they are, then back up the grub.cfg file as that holds all your current configuration for GRUB2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to boot to your 100 GB installation, which you have already verified by saying you're satisfied with it. Just load **Gparted** from the repository and remove the 15 GB partition.

If you have data saved on the 15 GB partition back it up.

You don't uninstall Ubuntu (per se), you just delete the unwanted partitions and allocate the space as you see fit.

You can add the unallocated 15 GB to your 100 GB partition by booting to the Live Ubuntu Media and run Gparted from there.  It's already installed on the Live Ubuntu install disk.

Resize your 100 GB partition to include the extra space.  When Gparted finishes, it will automatically retain the same UUID for the 100 GB partition, which the already installed working grub will see.  It's continue to boot to the working Partition.

After you finish the Gparted maintenance, run this command to remove the residue of the previous install (the menu items relating to it in the Grub menu):

```
$ sudo update-grub
```